# How to make ajax-like call in Android

Tags: android, ajax

I am working on Android application that will make consistent api calls to a server and parse JSON from the server. ( Actually this application is an web game.) Now we have an web version written with jQuery in which $.ajax() calls are used:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://www.example.com/api/base_info/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            "client_type": "web",
            "id": userID,
            "access_key": accessToken
        },
        success: function (data) {
            username = data.name;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

So how can I duplicate this in Android? I have searched on the internet and I see many different approaches. I am not sure which is best for Android platform? Would you please give some suggestions? Please use the code above as an example if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: a little too broad. I assume you know about HttpUrlConnection (or HttpClient) and AsyncTask?

Comment: You should change the title of the question, making an AJAX(J stands for javascript) call from android platform is actually impossible:)

Comment: Ajax is simply a construct to allow a web page to update only a portion of a page rather than load the entire page.   In order to do that in Android, you need simply to contact your server, get whatever data you need and display it.  There's nothing preventing you from loading a single data item on a screen so the notion of ajax is not really relevant here.